# Ajax lento e Validação do Login sem executar direito

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Boa noite,

Eu tenho um form aonde eu antes de acessar eu faço a validação com um ajax, php e mysql, essa validação verifica as tentativas de acesso, e se o usuario colocar 5 vezes a senha errada, ele bloqueia o acesso por 30 minutos, a cada sessão ele faz um insert na tabela "**tab_log_tentativa**", mesmo se o usuario for bloqueado, o problema é que ela não está trazendo o ip correto...Fora isso quando clico no botão entrar ele chama o ajax, enquanto está validando, só que o problema fica validando pra sempre e simplesmente não chama a tela **home** que é a principal, só quando eu atualizo a pagina ai sim ele entra na tela **home**, já refiz esse codigo 500 vezes e não arrumo...Se puderem me ajudar agradeço..meu codigo está assim:

Minha tabela de **usuario**:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nome varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   login varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   senha varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   acesso varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

tabela de acesso dos logins **tab_log_tentativa**:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_log_tentativa (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ip varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   login varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   senha varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
   origem varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
   bloqueado char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   data_hora timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Pagina de formulario **index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['logado']) &&  $_SESSION['logado'] == 'SIM'):
  header("Location: home.php");
endif;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo Login com AJAX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    #login-alert{
        display: none;
    }

    .margin-top-pq{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .margin-top-md{
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .margin-bottom-md{
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .padding-top-md{
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">    
        <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-7 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 margin-top-md">                    
            <div class="panel panel-primary" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Login - DevWilliam</div>
                </div>     

                <div class="panel-body padding-top-md" >
                    <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
                        <span id="mensagem"></span>
                    </div>      
                    <form id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="login.php" method="post">             
                        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-md">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="login" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" required placeholder="Informe seu Login">                                        
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-md">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" required placeholder="Informe sua Senha">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group margin-top-pq">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
                                  Entrar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </form>     
                </div>  

            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>  

    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Meu js com ajax chamado **custom.js**:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $("#btn-login").click(function(){
        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'login.php',
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                $("#btn-login").html('Validando ...');//fica validando sempre e não chama a home.php (só quando atualiza a pagina ai entra)
            },
            success :  function(response){                      
                if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                }
                else{           
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                    $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Minha pagina de validação chamada **login.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Constante com a quantidade de tentativas aceitas
define('TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS', 5); 

// Constante com a quantidade minutos para bloqueio
define('MINUTOS_BLOQUEIO', 30); 

// Require da classe de conexão
require 'configuracao.php';


// Dica 1 - Verifica se a origem da requisição é do mesmo domínio da aplicação

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://localhost:8080/contax/index.php"):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Origem da requisição não autorizada!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;

// Instancia Conexão PDO
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();

// Recebe os dados do formulário
$login = (isset($_POST['login'])) ? $_POST['login'] : '' ;
$senha = (isset($_POST['senha'])) ? $_POST['senha'] : '' ;


// Dica 2 - Validações de preenchimento login e senha se foi preenchido
if (empty($login)):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Preencha seu Login!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;

if (empty($senha)):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Preencha sua senha!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;

// Dica 4 - Verifica o Tipo de IP que o usuario está usando, mas não quer funcionar
function getUserIP()
{

    $http_client_ip       = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $http_x_forwarded_for = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote_addr          = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $http_cf_connecting_ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];

    /* VERIFICO SE O IP partiu do cloudflare*/
    if(!empty($http_cf_connecting_ip)){
        $ip = $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    /* VERIFICO SE O IP REALMENTE EXISTE NA INTERNET */
    }elseif(!empty($http_client_ip)){
        $ip = $http_client_ip;
        /* VERIFICO SE O ACESSO PARTIU DE UM SERVIDOR PROXY */
    } elseif(!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)){
        $ip =$http_x_forwarded_for;
    } else {
        /* CASO EU NÃO ENCONTRE NAS DUAS OUTRAS MANEIRAS, RECUPERO DA FORMA TRADICIONAL */
        $ip = $remote_addr;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();//Não quer funcionar

$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS tentativas, MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(data_hora))) AS minutos ";
$sql .= "FROM tab_log_tentativa WHERE ip = ? and DATE_FORMAT(data_hora,'%Y-%m-%d') = ? AND bloqueado = ?";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(1, $user_ip);//Não funciona pegar o IP
$stm->bindValue(2, date('Y-m-d'));
$stm->bindValue(3, 'SIM');
$stm->execute();
$retorno = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if (!empty($retorno->tentativas) && intval($retorno->minutos) <= MINUTOS_BLOQUEIO):
    $_SESSION['tentativas'] = 0;
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Você excedeu o limite de '.TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS.' tentativas, login bloqueado por '.MINUTOS_BLOQUEIO.' minutos!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;


// Dica 5 - Válida os dados do usuário com o banco de dados
$sql = 'SELECT id, nome, senha, login FROM usuario WHERE login = ? AND senha = ? AND acesso = ?';
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(1, $login);
$stm->bindValue(2, $senha);
$stm->bindValue(3, 'Ativo');
$stm->execute();
$retorno = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


// Dica 6 - Válida os dados e chama a sessão
if(!empty($retorno)):
    $_SESSION['id'] = $retorno->id;
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $retorno->nome;
    $_SESSION['login'] = $retorno->login;
    $_SESSION['tentativas'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['logado'] = 'SIM';
else:
    $_SESSION['logado'] = 'NAO';
    $_SESSION['tentativas'] = (isset($_SESSION['tentativas'])) ? $_SESSION['tentativas'] += 1 : 1;
    $bloqueado = ($_SESSION['tentativas'] == TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS) ? 'SIM' : 'NAO';

    // Dica 7 - Grava a tentativa independente de falha ou não
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tab_log_tentativa (ip, login, senha, origem, bloqueado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(1, $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $login);
    $stm->bindValue(3, $senha);
    $stm->bindValue(4, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $stm->bindValue(5, $bloqueado);
    $stm->execute();
endif;


// Se logado envia código 1, senão retorna mensagem de erro para o login
if ($_SESSION['logado'] == 'SIM'):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => 'Logado com sucesso!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
else:
    if ($_SESSION['tentativas'] == TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Você excedeu o limite de '.TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS.' tentativas, login bloqueado por '.MINUTOS_BLOQUEIO.' minutos!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    else:
        $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Usuário não autorizado, você tem mais '. (TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS - $_SESSION['tentativas']) .' tentativa(s) antes do bloqueio!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;
endif;
```

E por ultimo minha conexão com o banco que se chama **configuracao.php**:

```
<?php 
 /*  
  * Constantes de parâmetros para configuração da conexão  
  */  
 define('HOST', 'localhost');  
 define('DBNAME', 'login');  
 define('CHARSET', 'utf8');  
 define('USER', 'root');  
 define('PASSWORD', '1234');  

 class Conexao {  

   /*  
    * Atributo estático para instância do PDO  
    */  
   private static $pdo;

   /*  
    * Escondendo o construtor da classe  
    */ 
   private function __construct() {  
     //  
   } 

   /*  
    * Método estático para retornar uma conexão válida  
    * Verifica se já existe uma instância da conexão, caso não, configura uma nova conexão  
    */  
   public static function getInstance() {  
     if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {  
       try {  
         $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);  
         self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . ";", USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);  
       } catch (PDOException $e) {  
         print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();  
       }  
     }  
     return self::$pdo;  
   }  
 }
```

Resumindo o problema..o ajax não chama a pagina home.php mesmo estando login e senha corretos fica validando e só se eu atualizar a pagina ele entra na pagina principal home.php,(se a senha e login estiver errado ele mostra que está errado, essa parte funciona!) e o codigo não grava o ip na tabela..além de estar demorando horrores pra entrar no cadastro..quem puder me ajudar agradeço..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ragnar seu código aparentemente não possui erros e eu consegui executá-lo com algumas pequenas modificações. São elas:

1. Alterei de `$user_ip = getUserIP();` para `$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`. Veja esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623187/will-the-value-of-a-set-serverhttp-client-ip-be-an-empty-string) (em inglês) para mais informações.
2. Inseri `Ativo` manualmente na coluna `acesso` da tabela, pois a lógica elaborada não trata valores vazios/nulos.

Como identificar erros no código (debugar)?

- É uma boa prática em requisições ajax tratar o erro das requisições e no seu cenário como fazer isso? Utilizando o método [error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- Outra forma também é utilizar a ferramentas de desenvolvedor do browser (Geralmente tecla F12) na aba network clicar na requisição e abrir a aba response

Por último segue seu código jQuery alterado com o tratamento de errors:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#btn-login").click(function(){
        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'login.php',
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                $("#btn-login").html('Validando ...');//fica validando sempre e não chama a home.php (só quando atualiza a pagina ai entra)
            },
            success :  function(response){                      
                if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                }
                else{           
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                    $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // to do exibir alerta amigável para o usuário
                alert('Um erro aconteceu na requisição veja o console F12 para mais detalhes');
                $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Conclusão**

Seu código não possui erros, a falsa sensação de lentidão era devido devido a avisos lançado em seu código nos índices usados em $_SERVER dentro da função para pegar o ip do usuário que vinha junto com a resposta json tornando-o inválido para o jquery parsea-lo.

Comment: é isso mesmo, ele funcionou perfeito agora, ele entra de boa, só que o ip não grava de jeito nenhum..ele grava com resultado ::1 em todas as colunas..não sei pq isso,....mas mto obrigado mesmo, estou aprendendo php agora então to pegando agora essas facilidades do f12 e tals..mto obrigado vlw pelas dicas..

Comment: Ele está gravando `::1` pq é sua própria maquina em localhost

Comment: Depois que percebi kkk..vlw irmão